# How to develop custom login by auth middleware using laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to make a custom login system by auth middleware.
I don't have an idea how to do that.
`controller`

```php
public function dologin(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $username   = $request->username;
    $password   = $request->password;
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
    }
}
```

`Blade view`

```html
<form action="{{route('login.action')}}">
    <br>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>USERNAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--form-row-->
    <br>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>PASSWORD</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--form-row-->
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-success  col-md-3" id="signup-btn" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

`Route`

```php
// Login   
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@create')->name('login');
Route::get('/login/action', 'LoginController@dologin')->name('login.action');
```

Comment: You could just use the laravel auth login right? Why would you want to create your own custom version?

Comment: because i want to create own custom login not prebuild

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial. https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-6-custom-login-registration-example-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `LoginController` by runing this command in terminal:

```
php artisan make:controller LoginController
```

Then find your newly created controller under `App\Http\Controllers\` and add a the use of Auth at the top of your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Then add your `dologin` function to the controller and you're ready to go.

Comment: i want to know that what is the purpose of construct function ? why i use this function inside logincontroller

Comment: @ZubairMukhtar Every time you call your dologin method, the auth.basic will be called too. but now I'm noticing that you're calling the Auth::attempt inside your dologin method so no need to add the constructor.

Comment: you means  Auth::attempt  wil not be used inside dologin method ?

Comment: @ZubairMukhtar no, I mean you don't need the constructor inside your controller. Auth::attempt will work for you just fine